# inferred type is java.time.YearMonth! but org.threeten.bp.YearMonth was expected

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, calendarview

I'm currently using this library `com.github.kizitonwose:CalendarView:0.3.4` to show my calendar but I'm getting this error below when i just tried to see calendar;

This is the code;

```
    val currentMonth = YearMonth.now()
    val firstMonth = currentMonth.minusMonths(10)
    val lastMonth = currentMonth.plusMonths(10)
    val firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).firstDayOfWeek

    calendarViewForPublicHolidays.setup(firstMonth, lastMonth, firstDayOfWeek)
    calendarViewForPublicHolidays.scrollToMonth(currentMonth)
```

The error details are given below.

```
e: /Users/SimpleApp/app/src/main/java/com/holiday/officialholidays/CalendarActivity.kt: (53, 45): Type mismatch: inferred type is java.time.YearMonth! but org.threeten.bp.YearMonth was expected
```

Comment: Check your imports. You have imported `java.time.YearMonth`. You should import `org.threeten.bp.YearMonth` instead.

Comment: @Sweeper I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was because of the import like you said. I changed it and it worked fine.